# Advanced Algebra Question

Tags: polynomials

If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ such that
   $$f(0) = f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = 1$$
   and
   $$f(4) = 0,$$
   then determine $f(5)$.

```
   How would I do this? Any simple formula or theorem?
```

Comment: Similar techniques as used here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032335/constructing-a-cubic-given-four-points/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define
\begin{align}
p(x) = f(x)-1
\end{align}
then we see that $0, 1, 2, 3$ are its roots which means
\begin{align}
p(x) = cx(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
p(4) = f(4)-1 = -1 = c4!.
\end{align}
Hence $c = -1/4!$. Now finish the problem.

Comment: $c=\dfrac{-1}{24}$, not $\dfrac{-1}{4}$

Comment: @JenkinsMa  $4! = 1\times 2\times 3\times 4$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$f(x)-1=a\,x\,(x-1)\,(x-2)\,(x-3)$$

Answer (score 1):

A arbitrary polynomial of degree $4$ is $p(x)=a_4x^4+a_3a^3+...a_1x+a_0.$ Put the given conditions and find the coefficients.

Comment: It should be helpful to insist on the fact that you generate in this way a linear system with as many equations as there are unknowns and that this system has in fact a nonzero main determinant...