# find any polynomial of degree 4 or less that goes through the following points

Tags: numerical-methods

$(-2, 8), (0, 4), (1, 2), (3, -2)$

Using the method of Newton's divided differences I found that $p(x) = 4 - 2x$ goes through these points.  I have to find any other polynomial of degree 4 or less that also goes through these 4 points.

What I did was add another point and used the method of Newton's divided differences again and found a polynomial of degree 4, but it only went through the new point and not the others.  It was a hellish computation too.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032335/constructing-a-cubic-given-four-points/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: let $q(x)$ be any $4^{th}$ degree polynomial which is $0$ at $x=-2,0,1,3\,$. Then $p(x)+q(x)$ will pass through those same points.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  I defined $q(x) = x(x+2)(x-1)(x-3)$, which is certainly zero at $x = -2, 0, 1, 3$ but the sum of this with $p(x)$ doesn't go through all of the points, unless I made a computational error.

Comment: @BootScootin'Pootton $p(x)+q(x)=p(x)$ at all points where $q(x)=0$ so you must be making some computational error. Same goes for $p(x) + \lambda q(x)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $q(x)$ is a degree-four-or-less polynomial that passes through those points, then $q(x)-p(x)$ is a degree-four-or-less polynomial that has roots at $-2,0,1$ and $3$.