# If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 5 and $f(1)$=1, $f(2)$=3, $f(3)$=5, $f(4)$=7, $f(5)$=9, then find the value of $f(6)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I require to know the shortest way to solve it. I can solve it by taking $f(x)$ = $ax^5$ + $bx^4$ + $cx^3$ + $dx^2$ + $ex$ + $f$ and then substituting values of 1,2,3,4 and 5 in place of x and forming different equations. The equations can then be solved to find the polynomial. After finding the polynomial f(6) can be calculated.
But, I want a short way to do it. The above mentioned way is very tedious and long. Please provide me with suitable answers.

Comment: That's insufficient information; one needs the value of a degree $5$ polynomial at six points in order to determine it.

Comment: Is $f$ specified to be monic? Or is there anything else we know about it?

Comment: Similar type of problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032335/constructing-a-cubic-given-four-points/). The methods are valid for polynomials of any degree provided you have sufficient value available.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\;f(x)-2x+1$ has $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ as roots.

Answer (score 0):

In this case any polynomial of the form
$$f(x)=2x-1+b(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$$
works so $f(6)$ can be anything (except $11$ which would force $f$ to have degree $1$ not $5$).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $f(x)=\prod_{r=1}^6(x-r)\left[\sum_{s=1}^6\dfrac{A_s}{x-s}\right]$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-(2x-1)$. Then $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ and it has the roots $1,2,3,4,5$. Then $f(x)=k(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)+(2x-1)$ for some constant $k$ which will be the leading coefficient of $g$ and hence $f$. So $f(6)=k(5!)+11$.

Comment: Thanks for noticing..I have edited likewise